# how to write a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys actually i want to write this code shortly, instead of rewriting the same code for all my 4 elements individually i would like to write a function that will be called for each element and execute.

```
$(function(){
$('#basic').mouseover(function(){
    $('#table-one').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
    });
$('#basic').mouseout(function(){
    $('#table-one').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
    });

});

$(function(){
$('#standard').mouseover(function(){
    $('#table-two').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
    });
$('#standard').mouseout(function(){
    $('#table-two').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
    });

 });   

 $(function(){
$('#pro').mouseover(function(){
    $('#table-three').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
    });
$('#pro').mouseout(function(){
    $('#table-three').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
    });

});

  $(function(){
$('#expert').mouseover(function(){
    $('#table-four').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
    });
$('#expert').mouseout(function(){
    $('#table-four').css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
    });

});
```

Comment: It would be better if you can provide a link or jsfiddle with all of your code in so we can see the whole picture. 
However, it looks as though you could use a class and with the jquery select that class, then find a table within that class.

Comment: are the tables within the elementyou are mousing over? a bit of html would be helpful

Comment: Why don't you use the function that I gave you in this post of yours:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588362/i-want-to-write-a-reusable-function/17588504#17588504
?

Comment: @HugoY.K. If it does work, why don't you accept it as an answer then? :)

Comment: how do i do it, am new user here

Comment: I think it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

You should add a data attribute to your markup, linking the triggering element (`#standard` etc) to the table you want to hilight. In general, it's wise to semantically link related elements so that code can be as generic as possible, and apply to a wide range of elements on your page:

```
<div id="standard" data-table="#table-one">
...
</div>
```

Now, all of your elements can use the same handlers:

```
$(function () {

  $('#basic, #standard, #pro, #expert').mouseOver(function () {
    $($(this).data("table")).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
  }).mouseout(function () {
    $($(this).data("table")).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
  });

});
```

*note*: You don't need to wrap each and every block in a `$(function () { })`. One, around the whole blob of code you posted, would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
function mouseIn(target) {
    $('#table-' + target).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
}

function mouseOut(target) {
    $('#table-' + target).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
}
```

Then use them as such:

```
$('#expert').hover(
    function() {
        mouseIn('four');
    }, function() {
        mouseOut('four');
    }
);
```

**EDIT:** A more overkill (weeehooo) solution would be to iterate over it all and set it up:

```
var objs = {'basic': 'one', 'standard': 'two', 'pro': 'three', 'expert': 'four'};
for (var key in objs) {
    $('#' + key).hover(
        function() {
            $('#table-' + objs[key]).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
        }, function() {
            $('#table-' + objs[key]).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned and shortened your code a bit:

```
$(function(){
    $('#basic').mouseover(function(){
        animateIn('#table-one');
        }).mouseout(function(){
        animateOut('#table-one');
        });
    $('#standard').mouseover(function(){
        animateIn('#table-two');
        }).mouseout(function(){
        animateOut('#table-two');
        });
    $('#pro').mouseover(function(){
        animateIn('#table-three');
        }).mouseout(function(){
        animateOut('#table-three');
        });
    $('#expert').mouseover(function(){
        animateIn('#table-four');
        }).mouseout(function(){
        animateOut('#table-four');
        });
    function animateIn(id) {
        $(id).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
    }
    function animateOut(id) {
        $(id).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
    }
});
```

Should work, tell me if it does not

Comment: It does thank u mate, this ---> function animateIn(id) {
        $(id).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)" });
    }

was what i was looking for this morning thanks again
    function animateOut(id) {
        $(id).css({ boxShadow : "0 0 0 0" });
    }

Comment: You're welcome, happy to solve your question! You should accept a answer to mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

If the table is inside the container you can do

```
 $('#basic', '#standard', '#pro', '#expert').mouseover(function () {
     $(this).find("table").css({
         boxShadow: "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)"
     });
 }).mouseout(function () {
     $(this).find("table")..css({
         boxShadow: "0 0 0 0"
     });
 });
```

Otherwise you have to use a mapping object

```
 var map = {
     "basic": "table-one",
     "standard": "table-two",
     "pro": "table-three",
     "expert": "table-four"
 };

 $('#basic', '#standard', '#pro', '#expert').mouseover(function () {
     $("#" + map[this.id]).css({
         boxShadow: "0 0 5px 3px rgba(100,100,200,0.4)"
     });
 }).mouseout(function () {
     $("#" + map[this.id]).css({
         boxShadow: "0 0 0 0"
     });
 });
```

just the idea of how you can do it. code is not tested.